# Finding those pixels that meet a specific criterion

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, pixel, fuzzy-c-means

Attached is an image of `cameraman.tif` that comes with matlab but after applying `[fuzzy c-means]` [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6XsC.jpg)

[image]

Also, as an output from the algorithm is `u2` (degree of membership of a pixel). See [matlab.mat](https://www.dropbox.com/l/XUEyZHZhZmHXqqxX) for this data.

What I want to do is select the pixel(s) from the image attached whose `u2` value is `equal to 1`.

Any ideas on how this can be done in `matlab`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Get the indices of the appropriate pixels:

```
ind = find( u2 == 1 ); % return indices of all pixels with u2 eq to 1
```

Get the pixels themselfs

```
pixels = img( ind );
```

Comment: When I do this for `u2`, I get: `ind = Empty matrix: 0-by-1` although there are values equal to `1`. Why is that? Thanks

Comment: This might be due to numerical issues. How about `find( abs(u2-1) < 1e-6 )`?

Comment: When I checked `matlab.mat`, when you look at the cell value it says `1.0000`. But, when I double-click the cell I amazingly get: `0.999999999259113`! That seems why I get an empty matrix as a return value...

Comment: Your solution gives the results of from `u2`. But, I want to map that to the pixels in the original image. How can I get the pixels from the original image whose `u2 -- 1`? Thanks

Comment: @Med-SWEng what is the shape (`size`) of `u2`? is it the same as that of the image? if so - the indices are the same. You may get row/column locations using `[rows cols] = find( abs(u2-1)<1e-6 );`

Comment: @shai.Yes, `u2` has the same size as image

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by `abs(u2-1)<1e-6 `? Thanks

Comment: Si, when I use `[rows cols] = find(u2 == 1)` for instance, and I get the locations of those pixels from `u2` equal to `1`. In my output, how would I return those locations from the original image?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24832/discussion-between-shai-and-med-sweng)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can avoid using find and go straight into [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/).

Given an image as:

```
>> image = [1 3 5; 2 3 1; 3 2 2]

image =

     1     3     5
     2     3     1
     3     2     2
```

you can find the pixels with value 2 using the condition iamge == 2:

```
K>> image == 2

ans =

     0     0     0
     1     0     0
     0     1     1
```

If for instance you want to manipulate these pixels by setting them to 7 you can easily do that with a single line:

```
image(image == 2) = 7

image =

     1     3     5
     7     3     1
     3     7     7
```